# Page cannot be found

Tags: dd4t

I am running DD4T [following this example](http://remcorakers.nl/dd4t-development-environment/). I have things working but I always get a "Page cannot be found" error and I can't figure out what I am missing. Here is what I have. Page created in Tridion and published. That page uses my default page type that has a metadata schema on it with a "views" field and that value is "Default"

[image]

I have also validate that the page published and that my local storage config is pointed to that same database.

[image]

Here is what the DD4T logs tell me.

```
2014-06-13 17:06:11,984 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>TryFindPage (/index.aspx
2014-06-13 17:06:12,025 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - about to load page from cache with key Page_/index.aspx_0
2014-06-13 17:06:12,026 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - finished loading page from cache with key Page_/index.aspx_0, page found = False
2014-06-13 17:06:12,026 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - about to load page content from provider with url /index.aspx
2014-06-13 17:06:12,031 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - >>GetContentByUrl(/index.aspx)
2014-06-13 17:06:12,031 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to create query
2014-06-13 17:06:12,730 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: created query
2014-06-13 17:06:12,753 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: added criteria to query
2014-06-13 17:06:12,754 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: about to execute query
2014-06-13 17:06:13,944 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: executed query
2014-06-13 17:06:14,444 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - GetContentByUrl: executed PageContentAssembler
2014-06-13 17:06:14,445 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <<GetContentByUrl(/index.aspx)
2014-06-13 17:06:14,445 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - finished loading page content from provider with url /index.aspx, has value: False
2014-06-13 17:06:14,445 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <<TryFindPage (/index.aspx
```

Why is it not finding the page?

update: 
here is what cd_core log has.

```
2014-06-13 15:31:09,515 ERROR Query - Unable to execute Broker Query, no QueryGenerator was initialized
2014-06-13 15:33:04,058 ERROR DynamicContent - can't read cd_dynamic configuration, check if configuration file is on right place
com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ cd_dynamic_conf.xml ]
    at com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReader.java:92) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.loadConfiguration(DynamicContent.java:126) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.<init>(DynamicContent.java:90) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.reloadInstance(DynamicContent.java:76) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.getInstance(DynamicContent.java:68) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler.configure(PageContentAssembler.java:158) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler.<init>(PageContentAssembler.java:46) [cd_dynamic.jar:na]
2014-06-13 16:20:10,398 ERROR PageContentAssembler - PagePresentationAssembler:getContent(String, String) got invalid uri's as parameter, returning ""
```

Comment: Is there anything in the cd_core.log?

Comment: Was not aware of that log file. See update for error that was logged in it. I actually think that was an earlier problem that was solved. That config file is now in the bin/config folder of the app.

Comment: These log files (stagging and HttpUpload) don't get updated at all anymore when I make a call.

Comment: Is there more to the trace in the DD4T log past this: PageContentAssembler 2014-06-13 17:06:14,445 [62] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <?  I wonder if it's dying at the Broker API or after that successfully returns and dying on the DD4T/MVC side.  If so, you should be able to step through to the exact line.

Comment: Best I can do is step to the base.Page(pageId) call. It errors on that with the Page cannot be found error. I have no debug symbols for DD4T so can't step in. Here is some more after PageContentAssembler:
GetContentByUrl: executed PageContentAssembler
2014-06-13 21:09:02,007 [13] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <<GetContentByUrl(/index.aspx)
2014-06-13 21:09:02,007 [13] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - finished loading page content from provider with url /index.aspx, has value: False
2014-06-13 21:09:02,008 [13] DEBUG Performance [(null)] - <<TryFindPage (/index.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should also verify that the page is actually being published to the database and not the default file system. Check `cd_storage_conf.xml` item type mappings for page location in the httpupload for staging web application.

Comment: Thanks @SheltonP that was it. Figured I was missing a config setup. I was looking at that just a bit ago wondering. Still trying to wrap my head around that concept but I was wondering if it should have been going to the file system. Soon as I changed it all was good. Thanks guys!! Now I can sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing some config files in your /bin/config folder.  The Broker API is complaining that it can't find cd_dynamic_conf.xml:

ERROR DynamicContent - can't read cd_dynamic configuration, check if configuration file is on right place com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ cd_dynamic_conf.xml ]

Comment: ya, see my previous comment about that. That error is a previous issue that has been resolved. first log file notes a time of 17:06. The cd_core is from 15:33. I have verified that config file is there now and adding that is what got me from the "object reference not set..." error to this one.

Comment: Just had a thought... Is your cd_storage_conf set to point to the correct Broker DB instance?  Maybe accidentally it's pointing to session preview or another environment instance?

Comment: Nope. pointed to databaseName=Tridion_Broker_Staging on the same database server I did my query on.